# How can I create django model which implement lesson in timetable?

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, django-models

I'm trying to create a timetable system for classroom in Django. I have an idea which I am still wondering that i will work or not. Here is the model represent each lesson in class; lesson 1(7:00 AM - 7:50), lesson 2(7:50 - 8:40), etc.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
start = models.TimeField()
end = models.TimeField()
lesson = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 10)], primary_key=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'lesson'
    ordering = ['lesson']

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.lesson)
```

What I need here is creating 10 lessons starting from 7:00 am and lasting 50 minutes each. I'd love to here your precious advises. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a Lesson object?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is create ten Lesson *objects*, each with its own start and end time. In this case, I would set up the model like this:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        start_time = self.start.strftime("%H:%M")  # '07:00'
        end_time = self.end.strftime("%H:%M")      # '07:50'
        return "{} ({} - {})".format(self.title, start_time, end_time)
                                                   # 'Course 1 (07:00 - 07:50)
```

Then you could create a separate script to populate the objects.

```
courses = ['Course 1', 'Course 2', ..., 'Course 10']
start_time = datetime.time(7,0)   # 07:00
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=50)
for course in courses:
    date_time = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), start_time)
    time_diff = date_time + delta
    end_time = time_diff.time()
    lesson = Lesson(start=start_time, end=end_time, title=course)
    lesson.save()

    start_time = end_time
```

This would result in 10 Lesson records being created in your database, each back-to-back with 50 minute durations.

If you want your users to choose courses from a dropdown menu, you can still populate the menu using the unique course titles from the database, using `Lesson.objects.values('title').distinct()`